# Problema con Windows 10 al cambiar de conexión pública a privada

Tags: windows10

Hola comunidad de Stackoverflow,

Como dice la pregunta tengo ciertos inconvenientes al cambiar mi conexión de modo público a privada. El proceso lo realizo como muestro a continuación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pués bien mi problema radica en que cuando la red se encuentra en modo privado tengo problemas con 2 aplicaciones de Windows 10.

1. La aplicación de correo de Windows me muestra los mensajes pero con símbolos de error en las imágenes como muestro a continuación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2. La Tienda de Windows 10 me muestra los íconos de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y al ingresar en la zona de descargas -> Listo para Instalar, de la misma tienda me aparece el siguiente mensaje:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hasta el momento he revisado ya varios foros de soporte de Microsoft sin ninguna solución efectiva. He probado deshabilitar el Firewall, también sin resultados.

Debo recalcar que es solo cuando pongo la conexión en privada, en pública todo funciona perfectamente; desafortunadamente necesito la configuración de red privada para hacer algunas pruebas de aplicaciones web en entorno local.

Si alguién tuviera alguna sugerencia al respecto estaré muy agradecido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Habiendo pasado casi un mes desde la publicación de la pregunta (sin ningún comentario o respuesta), he de decir que el día de hoy realicé algunas pruebas en la aplicación de correo y tienda en modo red privada de nuevo y cargó los mensajes e imágenes sin problemas.

Revisando un poco me he percatado que recientemente Windows ha lanzado una serie de actualizaciones, por lo que, lo más lógico sería pensar que se trataba de un bug en una build anterior y al lanzar el conjunto de actualizaciones del 13/11/2018 se haya arreglado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como dato adicional revisando la documentación oficial de la actualización [KB4467708](https://support.microsoft.com/es-pe/help/4467708/windows-10-update-kb4467708)  de Windows 10, se puede apreciar un punto que dice: **Se solucionó un problema en el que se denegaba el acceso al sistema de archivos para las apps de la Plataforma universal de Windows de Internet of Things (IoT) que necesitan esta capacidad**.